# How to reduce `.via()` down a Seq of custom GraphStage?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I have concrete subclass of `GraphStage` that defines some custom logic that is influenced by the class parameters.

I would like users of my application to be able to supply a `Seq` of these custom `GraphStages`. When building the `RunnableGraph` I would like to add edges between the `Source` and the first stage in the `Seq`, then between each stage in order, and finally the `Sink`. In other words: `src ~> stages.reduce(_ ~> _) ~> sink`

Unfortunately this doesn't compile. I think the reason might be related to operator precedence. I tried being more explicit using `.via` or `.foldLeft` but I couldn't quite get it right.

This feels like this kind of thing should have a fairly straightforward syntax. Am I missing an operator in the docs? Is this kind of dynamic graph not possible for some reason?

Below is a fabricated example of this pattern using simple stages of `String => String`. It includes my incompilable code that logically represents the graph I want to express.

```scala
import akka.NotUsed
import akka.stream.scaladsl.{GraphDSL, RunnableGraph, Sink, Source}
import akka.stream.stage.{GraphStage, GraphStageLogic}
import akka.stream._

import scala.concurrent.Future

case class MyStage[T](/* ... params ... */) extends GraphStage[FlowShape[T, T]] {
  val in = Inlet[T]("MyStage.in")
  val out = Outlet[T]("MyStage.out")
  val shape: FlowShape[T, T] = FlowShape.of(in, out)
  def createLogic(inheritedAttributes: Attributes): GraphStageLogic = ??? // Depends on params
}


case class MyApp(stages: Seq[MyStage[String]]) {
  val out = Sink.seq[String]

  val graph = RunnableGraph.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create(out) { implicit b: GraphDSL.Builder[Future[Seq[String]]] =>
    sink =>
      import GraphDSL.Implicits._
      
      val src: Source[String, NotUsed] = Source(Seq("abc", "hello world", "goodbye!"))

      // This is what I logically want to do.
      src ~> stages.reduce(_ ~> _) ~> sink

      ClosedShape
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create flow of your stages like this:

```
     val graph = GraphDSL.create() { implicit b =>
          import GraphDSL.Implicits._

          val stagesShapes = stages.map(b.add(_))

          stagesShapes.reduce { (s1, s2) => 
            s1 ~> s2
            FlowShape(s1.in, s2.out)
          }
      }
```

Then all you need is connect source and sink to this flow and run it.

Comment: Thanks for the working code, I am happy to accept this answer but could you elaborate on what each line of the body of the `reduce` is doing? I don't understand why the `FlowShape(s1.in, s2.out)` is needed.

Comment: It's needed because you need `FlowShape`. `s1 ~> s2` returns `PortOps`. There could be more connections, more inputs and outputs, but for `FlowShape` you need to choose exactly one input and one output. It's obvious in this case, but in other cases it might be more complicated.